# Implement a Caesar Cipher with a Digit Shift

Tags: code-golf, string

I assume everyone here is familiar with the Caesar Cipher that shifts letters to a certain index. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher for those who still needs introduction.

But, we can all agree that plain Caesar is unfun and way too easy. So here's a version that also shifts characters around. This version first applies a cyclic position shift of a given amount to the string, for each character in the string separated with punctuations (space counts as character in this context, positive index means to the right).

For example, `Hello world` with shift +3 becomes `rldHello wo`.
`Hello! World` becomes `lloHe!rld Wo` with the same shift however because the ! separated the string.

After that, your program applies the Caesar cipher to the shifted text, and outputs the result. (easy enough)
The first example becomes `uogKhoor zr` after the Caesar cipher of +3.
The second example becomes `iilEb!oia Tl` after a Caesar shift of -3 (or +23 in alphabets)

As seen above, the index of the two shifts may or may not be equal.

**Task**

Write a encode and decode program or function (or whatever your language of choice calls them), they may or may not be the same one. It must implement the aforementioned rules of double shifting, and the decode function must successfully reverse it.

**Conditions**

Your program must at the very least function on ASCII characters, ASCII 0-9 (48-57, inclusive), A to Z (65-90), a to z (97-122) and Space (32) counts as characters in this context, with every other ASCII character counting as punctuation and breaking up the string.

Bonus points to those whose program functions on your language of choice's codebase. Since non-ASCII language contain special characters the "punctuation" rule is omitted in this use case. You only need to implement the cyclic shift and then the Caesar shift on your language's codebase.
`¡¢£¤` in Jelly becomes `©¤¥¦` with a position shift of +1 and Caesar shift of -253.

**You may assume:**

The index input are integers. It may be negative or zero.
If only one number is provided, encode both shifts with that number.
If no number is provided, perform whatever default shifts your heart desire (except 0 and 0, that is boring).
**Edit: Due to overwhelming demand, you may assume that there will be at least one number provided. Code that has defaults would still be preferred but no extra scoring.**
The input string is in ASCII. Or in your language's codebase if you decide to input that to your program.

**Scoring**

Of course programs that successfully include their codebase will be prioritized. Include the shifted version of your program in your answer to reflect this.

The other criteria is lowest byte wins. This counts both the encoder and decoder. List the sum and respective length separately please.

**Test cases**

```
+3 -5 "Hello,world" becomes "ggjCz,mgyrj"
+10 "Implement a Caesar Cipher with a Digit Shift" becomes "sqsd Crspd Swzvowoxd k Mkockb mszrob gsdr k N"
-2 -11 "Caesar cipher, also known as Caesar's cipher, the shift cipher, Caesar's code or Caesar shift." 
becomes "thpg rxewtgRp,ahd zcdlc ph Rpthpg p'rxewtgh ,wt hwxui rxewtg i,pthpg'h rdst dg Rpthpg hwxui R."
```

PS. Of course I am aware that the two shifts can be carried out in any order and produce the same result, it is just my way of visualizing things. Plus, the first input means position shift index.

PPS. If the test cases are wrong I apologize, I am not a good coder.

Comment: The punctuation also breaks up for the cycles? Or should I cycle the WHOLE string and then only _encode_ the characters you mentioned?

Comment: @RGS Yes the punctuation always break the ASCII string, this for obvious reasons does not apply to your language's codebase.

Comment: "_If no number is provided, perform whatever default shifts your heart desire (except 0 and 0, that is boring)._" Is this mandatory? I have a solution which I was about to post, but adding this requirement would make both the encoder and decoder almost twice as large.. My current solution does work for both 1 and/or 2 shift-integers, though. PS: I would advice to let answers assume we always get three inputs (1 string and 2 integers).

Comment: edited to waive defaults

Comment: What should happen to values which push above Z in ASCII, should they map down to A or map up in the ASCII range? Also, why do spaces get special treatment in the rotation but not in the transformation? Is it ok to transform both?

Comment: *we can all agree that plain Caesar is unfun and way too easy* -- extremely, *extremely* broad generalization

Comment: "[the programs] may or may not be the same one." - If they are the same one, must we take four inputs or may we just take the negative of the shifts (the latter would probably mean everyone does). Also do we then count the bytes of the one program once or twice?

Comment: "If only one number is provided, encode both shifts with that number." - Oh this invalidates my answer, and the other Jelly answer. This is a very unusual request and seems to be unrelated to the core of the challenge.

Comment: What's the desired shift for a digit?

Comment: And lastly again, shouldn't the encoding of the second example be `"sqsd CrspdSwzvowoxd k Mkockb Mszrob gsdr k N"` (you have a space in `Crspd Swzvowoxd`) and encoding for the third example should be `"thpg rxewtgRp,ahd zcdlc ph Rpthpg p'rxewtgh ,wt hwxui rxewtg i,pthpg'h rdst dg Rpthpg hwxui R."`?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what should happen on the Caesar shift when input is say `Z` and shift is `+1`? Is the result `A`, `a` or `[`?

Comment: So `Bonus points to those whose program functions on your language of choice's codebase. Since non-ASCII language contain special characters the "punctuation" rule is omitted in this use case. You only need to implement the cyclic shift and then the Caesar shift on your language's codebase.`.  Are you saying that "non-ASCII languages" (please clarify exactly what that means) not only will get a "bonus" for a submission, but are also not required to fulfill a part of the challenge that "ASCII languages" are?

Comment: Above comment see Meta ["Things to avoid when writing challenges"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10003/84624), [and this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/84624), [and on bonuses](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8106#8106).

Comment: "least function on ASCII characters, ASCII 0-9 (48-57, inclusive)" -> In the wiki page, the Caesar cipher' behaviour on numbers is not precised, should we assume it increments and loops on digits? (`5` becomes `6`; `9` becomes `0` etc?)

Comment: I think it should be noted that spaces are preserved in Caesar cipher, in case people miss it. Also I think your last example is wrong (see my answer). Oh and I loved your "Foundation" serie (probably mistaken here :)

Comment: I'd suggest eliminating the "optional" or variable parameters as I don't think it adds anything and is [discouraged in challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/84624). Making the input simply two integers and a string is typical and would be more inclusive to all languages and platforms.  All of my comments are to say that I think this is a great challenge and if some of these issue can be corrected to conform to CCGC conventions it would receive a lot more attention and answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 23 (12+11) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Uses the [05AB1E encoding](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) for the Caesar-shifting.

**Encoder:**

```
žĆDII(._kI+è
```

Input order as `string`, `shift`, (optional `Caesar-shift`). I/O of the strings as character-list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbS6enhp68dme2odX/P8freShpKOUCsQ5UJwPxCBYDmUXQcVTlGK5jLl0TQE) or [try it online with debug step-by-step lines and single shift-input](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fyTk/JbUgMT3VSkHJ/ui@I222LlxKnnkFpSUKxRmZaSWpKSAJF09PDb14W5BMSmZyarFCZp5CMpLGbKCUY0oKRAtQsiQ1PbUIJOGpDdGUWgESzUfRdHiFzv//0UoeSjpKqUCcA8X5QAyC5VB2EVQ8RSmWyxgA).

**Decoder:**

```
žĆDIkI-èI._
```

Input order as `string`, (optional `Caesar-shift`), `shift`. I/O of the strings as character-list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbS6e2Z66h1d46sX//x@tlKuko6CUDiLiQYQziEiAi4GJLBChDiKKINxYLl1TLmMA) or [try it online with debug step-by-step lines and single shift-input](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fyTk/JbUgMT3VSkHJ/ui@I222LlxKnnkpmcmpxQr5aQrFJUWZeem6mXkFpSUgJZ7ZtlxKwaVJJUWJySUKxRmZaSVAyZLU9NQisLSuLVh7aoUCUDRfIRnJ9MMrQFpBOsAq9eJ1/v@PVipV0lHKB@J0IPYG4gwoH4SLgFgfiKvA7FguYwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
              # ENCODER:
žĆ            # Push the 05AB1E codepage
  D           # Duplicate it
   I          # Push the first character-list input
    I         # Push the second shift integer
     (        # Negate it
      ._      # Shift the character-list that many times towards the left
        k     # Get the index of each character in the duplicated codepage
         I    # Push the second shift input again or the optional third Caesar-shift input
          +   # Add it to each index
           è  # And index it into the 05AB1E codepage
              # (after which the resulting character-list is output implicitly as result)

              # DECODER:
žĆ            # Push the 05AB1E codepage
  D           # Duplicate it
   I          # Push the first character-list input
    k         # Get the index of each in the duplicated codepage
     I        # Push the optional Caesar-shift or shift integer
      -       # Subtract it from each index
       è      # Index it into the 05AB1E codepage
        I     # Push the second/third shift integer
         ._   # And rotate the character-list that many times towards the left
              # (after which the resulting character-list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (8 + 11 = 19?) 11 + 14 = 25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Uses the code-page, no punctuation option

19 + 6 = 25 bytes handling the `only 1 number option` by taking a list of numbers as one of the two arguments.

**[Encoder +](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g4e7uwzO8dB7unHloaSWQfNS44@GORf///4821jE0iP2vlAFUmK9Qnl@Uk6KoBAA):** (`Shift(s), plaintext`)

```
0ịØJ,ṙ¥yṙ⁸Ḣ
```

**[Decoder +](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g4e5uv8MzvHQe7px5aGklkHzUuMPv0JKHOxb9//8/2ljH0CD2v1JZpdahnZU1ZXnaRfllSgA):** (`Shift(s), cyphertext`)

```
0ịNØJ,ṙ¥yṙ⁸N¤Ḣ
```

These Links build on the below programs:

**[Encoder](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDC@dhztnHlpaCSQfNW79//@/ocF/pQygbL5CeX5RToqi0n9jAA):** (`Caesar shift, plaintext, Cyclic shift`)

```
ØJ,ṙ¥yṙ⁵
```

**[Decoder](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/v8AwvnYc7Zx5aWgkkHzVu9Tu05P///4YG/5XKKrUO7aysKcvTLsovU/pvDAA):** (`Caesar shift, cyphertext, Cyclic shift`)

```
NØJ,ṙ¥yṙ⁵N¤
```

## How?

#### Encoder

```
ØJ,ṙ¥yṙ⁵ - Main Link: Caesar shift, plaintext
ØJ       - code-page characters
    ¥    - last two links as a dyad:
   ṙ     -   rotate (code-page) left by (Caesar shift)
  ,      -   (code-page) pair with (that)
     y   - (plaintext) translated using (that mapping)
       ⁵ - get program's 3rd argument (Cyclic shift)
      ṙ  - rotate (translated) left by (Cyclic shift)
         - implicit print
```

#### Decoder

```
NØJ,ṙ¥yṙ⁵N¤ - Main Link: Caesar shift, cyphertext
N           - (Caesar shift) negated
 ØJ         - code-page characters
     ¥      - last two links as a dyad:
    ṙ       -   rotate (code-page) left by (negated Caesar shift)
   ,        -   pair
      y     - (cyphertext) translated using (that mapping)
          ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
        ⁵   -   get program's 3rd argument (Cyclic shift)
         N  -   negated
       ṙ    - rotate (translated) left by (negated Cyclic shift)
            - implicit print
```

Comment: Really nice use of the `y` link here. More for for my brain! +1

Comment: Remember, it is not the spoon that bends, it is yourself :p

Comment: sorry for asking, but are you being serious or just joking? Sometimes sarcasm flies over my head xD

Comment: @RGS just joking around. Reference to The Matrix.

Comment: ah I see! Also, well played on handling the cases where no third argument is given.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki), <s>[25](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpmHth6e4ZX5aOM67UeNWx/u7gbyuIDCh3c8atziB5eMh0sC9bQc3viocSeIXv7/v1JuXn5Bdo7Sf6P/hgYA)</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page) (10 + 13)

```
ØJiⱮṙ+⁵ịØJ
ØJiⱮṙN}¥_⁵ịØJ
```

**Encoder**:

```
   Ɱ          For each character on the input string
  i           get its index on
ØJ            the Jelly code page.
    ṙ         Then rotate the list we get by as much as the cyclic shift input
     +⁵       and add to each number as much as the Caesar shift input.
       ị      Finally use those numbers to index 
        ØJ    on Jelly's code page again.
```

**Decoder**:

```
   Ɱ             For each character on the input string
  i              get its index on
ØJ               the Jelly code page.
    ṙ            Then rotate the list of indices
     N}¥         by the symmetric of the cyclic shift input.
        _⁵       Then subtract from each number as much as the Caesar shift input.
          ị      Finally use those numbers to index 
           ØJ    on Jelly's code page again.
```

@Jonathan saved me 2 bytes! Kudos to him :D

Inputs are the string to encode, the shift corresponding to the "rotation" of the string and the shift corresponding to the Caesar encoding. I am encoding the whole Jelly codepage.

You can [try the encoder](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDK/MRxvXPdw5U/tR49aHu7uBAv///1fKAErnK5TnF@WkKCr9N/5vaAAA) or [the decoder](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDK/MRxvXPdw506/20NL4R41bH@7uBgr@//9fqaxS69DOypqyPO2i/DKl/8b/DQ0A). You can also [check the encoder and decoder are the inverse of one another](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDK/MRxvXPdw5U/tR49aHu7uBAlwIQb/aQ0vj4RL/H@5sObzxUeNOEL38/3@lxKTklNQ0pf9G/w0NAA) (swap the order of the encoder/decoder to verify they are the inverses on both sides).

Comment: I am trying to write a footer to compose both links to show that their composition is the Identity function, but I am failing to write such a footer. Can someone give me a hint in the right direction? I think I am struggling with the fact that the two links I wrote have 3 arguments and the quicks I find are for links up to dyads...

Comment: Maybe place the third argument in the register [like this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpmHth6e4ZX5aOM67UPrHu7uBnK4gKKHdzxq3OIHl4t/1LgVIgnU0gLkHFp5YvnhjY8adwK5h5f//6@UmJSckpqm9N/ov6EBAA)?

Comment: Encoder can be simplified to `ØJiⱮṙ+⁵ịØJ`

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks! Can we chat for a couple of minutes? I don't fully understand the footer you used.

Comment: Also Decoder can be `ØJiⱮṙN}¥_⁵ịØJ`

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/104191/jelly-footer-for-caesar-shift

Comment: Our answers fail to handle the odd rule "If only one number is provided, encode both shifts with that number." :(

Comment: @JonathanAllan I read an OP comment saying the defaults were going to be waived and I assumed we could just take the 3 arguments, as per Kevin's suggestion comment...

Comment: The edit took out the 0 numeric input case but left the 1 numeric input case. Maybe it'll be relaxed...

Answer (score 0):

First version, a bit verbose yet, I'll try to optimize:

- "fully cyclic caesar" (`9`+1 becomes `0`, `z`+1 becomes `a`, `Z`+1 becomes `A`)
- breaks on anything not a space or char (`a-z A-Z 0-1`) (I think your last example is wrong, it breaks on the last `'`, which is intended)
- default values if missing: 1 / 1 (same value for both, could be up to 9 without extra byte)
- originally planned to use PHP's char increment, convenient way to loop over alpha values (`$c='Z';$c++;` makes `'AA'`), but decrement is not implemented (so no negative values or decoding)!
- should be prioritized IMO because it supports its own codebase, UTF-8 ;)

**ENCODER + DECODER = TOTAL**

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 430 + 71 = 501 bytes

```php
function a($a,$b='',$c=''){$b!==''?:$b=$c;$c!==''?:$c=$b;$t="/([^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/";preg_match_all($t,$a,$s);$r=preg_split($t,$a);for($i=0;null!==$d=$r[$i];$i++){if($j=strlen($d)){$n=-$b%$j;$d=substr($d,$n).substr($d,0,$n);for(;$j--;){if(' '!=$e=$d[$j]){$n=($t=ctype_digit($e))?10:26;$f=$c%$n+$e=ord($e);$d[$j]=chr($t&$f>57|$f>122|$e<91&$f>90?$f-$n:($t&$f<48|!$t&$f<65|$e>96&$f<97?$f+$n:$f));}}}$r[$i]=$d.$s[1][$i];}return join($r);}function b($a,$b='',$c=''){return a($a,$b!==''?-$b:'',$c!==''?-$c:'');}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFhk5owEIa/91dEZ6@SAVRsz6vGnHPTf1HLORCCxHKBSWJv2tPfTheQ88NNv4TdfZ@82WXrom422xrP/KSFU5UmiQdJACmfTAIQeNI3SEccg@0aqyAYiCEVHFIGjo9n3u45Cf8@hT/m4YrEPp2NWW3kYf@SOFHsk7L0wAWtr6UMDO80W5fK9XXK8sp4oPic6VNZoj9kHMwOVMxA@T59U7kHR26dKaX2IKPYleYhpHdwZMjaU4oaCgFoOr1l8zbvzBkcw5B1RhMyGXGQ@MYOjnHnhG1w4f7Ucp@pQ9uVpHQbzdeLJYMch74D7eONymStxPqbXBT4iPsM@eP9wxnPaLE4g9ysora0mm8hD0Gve2Tz9dt51EfLe6QeV8s2Xj0g5SMFOaXscrn0U2NvU7C7KO5@wcVIdzKaHCuFwxvk3reVftjWlb2usV8V/qh1RwypwBRtGimKioylFlUms1kmuy95Va4gtlC5I4k5nF6kdpYAhr93i5jMruGXeP1Tj9mnzgPQg7dvtkoUBwMdDCydjm80do38f6Gm@Z5ImxgiVF1IE5CktBX5patXnMuSXpzYd9kV8truULkhOBCpzLXQU9MmXDRhFP0D)

**BONUS - Encoder with line breaks and comments:** (not updated)

```php
$a=$argv;                     //arguments short alias
$b=$a[2]?$a[2]:$a[3];         //argument 1 defaults to 2 if missing
$c=$a[3]?$a[3]:($b?$b:$b=1);  //argument 2 defaults to 1 or both default to "1"
$t="/([^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/";      //breaking on anything not alpha or digit or space
preg_match_all($t,$a[1],$s);  //saving breaking chars for later
$r=preg_split($t,$a[1]);      //splitting at breaks
for($i=0;null!==$d=$r[$i];){  //for any non null split
    if($j=strlen($d)){                     //if it has a length
        $n=-$b%$j;                         //modulo for shifting
        $d=substr($d,$n).substr($d,0,$n);  //the shifting
        for(;$j--;){                       //for every char
            if(' '!=$e=$d[$j]){                //which is not a space
                $n=($t=ctype_digit($e))?10:26; //char code range depending if digit or alpha
                $f=$c%$n+$e=ord($e);           //new char code and save current one
                $d[$j]=chr($t&$f>57|$f>122|$e<91&$f>90?$f-$n:($t&$f<48|!$t&$f<65|$e>96&$f<97?$f+$n:$f));    //applying char code $f or using range $n to calculate if out
            }
        }
    }
    echo$d.$s[1][$i++];       //display current split with breaking chars
}
```

**BONUS 2 - shifted version of the program with -2 / -11:**

```php
crixdc puj($p,$q='',$r=''){$q!==''?:$q=$r;$r!==''?:$r=$q;$i="/([^p-oP-O9-8 ]+)/";tveg_irwbp_apa($i,$p,$h);$g=tveg_axihe($i,$p);gud($x=9;aacj!==$s=$g[$x];$x++){xu($y=gatchi($s)){$c=-$q%$y;$s=qhighj($s,$c).qhighj($s,9,$c);gud(;$y--;){xu(' '!=$t=$s[$y]){$c=($i=netri_vxisx($t))?09:15;$u=$r%$c+$t=sdg($t);$s[$y]=grw($i&$u>46|$u>101|$t<80&$u>89?$u-$c:($i&$u<37|!$i&$u<54|$t>85&$u<86?$u+$c:$u));}}}$g[$x]=$s.$h[0][$x];}ijgc ydxcgt($g);}crixdc quj($p,$q='',$r=''){ijgc pgt($p,$q!==''?-$q:'',$r!==''?-$r:'');}
```

EDIT: saved 10 bytes by refactoring to remove brackets + replaced `''!==` by `''!=` + replaced logical operators `||`/`&&` by bitwise `|`/`&`

EDIT2: saved 1 byte by using `$l=strlen(` in for declaration instead of `''!=` and reusing it after, but +4 bytes correcting a bug for `$f<65` picking numbers, changed to `!$t&$f<65`

EDIT3: fixed bug of prematurely breaking first loop when string begins by a punctuation, forces new `if` to prevent division by zero, but uses split length `$j` to shorten second loop declaration

EDIT4: improved with a function and advices from 640KB but didn't want to go too far while questions not resolved and didn't want to end with same code - gave up default values when both arguments miss, supports now zero shifting

Comment: Is your total score 830 then?  (the sum of both encode and decode)

Comment: hint: isn't the decode function just the encode function with the opposite signs of the two shift values? (ex: `function d($a,$b,$c) { return e(-$a,-$b,$c); }` (if that saves you any bytes :) )

Comment: Nice job you did using parameters for `preg_split`! Many valid points, but it's gonna be hard not end up with your code if I use all this ;) I also implemented default values although it doesn't add to the score.. maybe a bit dumb

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 398 bytes

```php
function e($z,$x,$y=null){$y=is_null($y)?$x:$y;for($i=0,$o=preg_split('/([^A-Za-z0-9 ])/',$z,0,2);$i<count($o);$o[$i]=$s,$i+=2)for($s=substr(($s=$o[$i]).$s.$s,($l=strlen($s))-$x,$l),$j=0;$j<strlen($s);$j++)if(($c=$s[$j])!=' ')$s[$j]=(chr(ctype_digit($c)?(ord($c)+$y-38)%10+48:(ord($c)+$y-($p=ctype_lower($c)?97:65)+26)%26+$p));return join($o);}function d($z,$x,$y=null){return e($z,-$x,-($y?:$x));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDfa9swEH7fX3GDK5aw3DpOm7V2hAljZYNCA31b8IJnK7EyYxnJXuOO/u2eHAe37Gmgh@/u@3Gnq4u6X8Z1UUO/a6uskaoCQfCF4ZFhx6u2LOkfC6TZDphgR2M8hthFO6UJSu4zVLzWYr81dSkb4lyRzY@V9z31XnzvDhJ65TAb57OARiiXmWqrhqCyhdqgTDgahtLlAT3lGW7an6bRZICjgl6isY8RLLllSlFZjlJvWLCkDA/cj/CwfKNs5bpU7mxGZuM3eEjoR@6AQ8eCk6zQJGu6Wmxzubc7Y0ZjonQ@ABc7b35LL2a@e30bvu8SrPnoKtWz0CfX3adwcUPdYEEvgoWLNaWRFk2rKzgoWZ3@@TrdNf/3rmfp6d7Df@yILg7xaFNee5EVClAAtzxgqve/N7OEnVEwoXkClMH663r75fEh@jC6cuvKrUv8v55PMyAGZ716enIghPvVt4eo7z@nwqQaMlkXQjNIS6PgV6WeK0gNjKRjJropBJhC7pqp8yZRuQClz41RdTkL5uz6ZtF7wV8)

Submitted as two functions:

- Encode: `e( $string, $index_shift, [ $caesar_shift ] ) : string`
- Decode: `d( $string, $index_shift, [ $caesar_shift ] ) : string`

Yes, this is not very golfed yet, but I thought it would be helpful to post to verify my assumptions about this challenge, while waiting for answers to my questions to the OP above.

Still unclear to me is:

1. Case of inputs `+1 "Z" == "A"`, `+1 "z" == "a"`, `+1 "9" == "0"`?
2. *Only* UTF-8 / ASCII languages are required to implement the "punctuation delimiter" rule?
3. Verify output with posted test cases, which as I've pointed out, I believe the second two are incorrect.

Comment: Only downsides I see to your code is that it's not precised in the question which index number can be missing, but in your case the first one cannot be missing. It's also precised for those numbers "It may be negative or zero", so zero should be a valid input, a different case than missing (but I actually made the same mistake too)

Comment: I've updated the solution to account for this, as I'm honestly not concerned about byte counts until some of open questions are answered.

Comment: I see what you are saying -- in the example `e( 'input', 1, 0 )` would imply `e( 'input, 1, 1 )` the way it is now. That said, as others have pointed out, having "optional" or "default" parameters is [discouraged in challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/84624) , and I'd suggest to the OP that this be more clearly changed to confirm to [Default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for challenges

Comment: updated my code, maybe you can save some bytes with default values as empty strings, it should work either if argument is empty or missing (calling with `null` will use default value)